# how can i return user of different structure from authorize to useSession() in nextAuth?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I'm new to learning nextJs and nextauth

`/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        let user = {
          id: "2",
          name: {
            fname: "sainath",
          },
          email: "sainsa@gmail.com",
          msg: "This is my message",
        };
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      console.log("in session callback: ", session);
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

but when i tried to console log the user, its undefined, i want the session.user to contain fname, msg how can i do it?
One thing which worked is to make an object that consists what i need and assign it "name" or "email"

`name : { fname: "sainath", msg:"this is my message" }`